# How do we send a byte of data with putty platform

Tags: putty

I am working with 115200 baude rate , i want to send 0x07 which is 0b00000111. i have defined the port and baud rate as shown bellow. Where do i send the digital data in the photo shown bellow? Thanks.

[image: putty screen]

Comment: You need to click "_Open_" (off the bottom of your screenshot) to open the port, and you'll then need to paste the 0x07 byte / character into PuTTY's terminal emulator... I suspect this isn't the tool for the job!

Comment: Hello, 0x07/ , or to add a space between the two?

Comment: @rocko - `/` is a separator character.  So `0x07/0x07` would send 8 bytes in total. `(01110111)` if I am not mistaken. However, I agree with the answer, you need to switch Putty into the correct mode otherwise Putty will attempt to send something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How do we send a byte of data with putty platform**

By **open**ing a connection and then using the keyboard to tell Putty to send the corresponding byte.

0x07 is Ctrl+G the BEL control-character in ASCII. Putty doesn't convert strings like 0x07 into binary, it would send that as four characters. Try holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while pressing <kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: i need to send 00000111 to my controller

Comment: @rocko - This answer is correct.

Comment: So by pressing CTRL+G it will send  0000 0111 in binary?
What is the full Table for other values in HEX?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko: http://redgrittybrick.org/charsets.html (block 1 is controls, block 3 is corresponding letters)  or any similar table. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305669/2974

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a byte of data (one character) in PuTTY terminal, you can convert it to decimal (for example 7), enable Num Lock on your keyboard, then press Alt, type that decimal and release Alt, the character will be sent.

You can check if it works by opening any editor and typing Alt + 97 - should result in 'a' character appearing.